# Cannot change content of list within list. Can anybody explain why?

Tags: python, list

I have a month variable which is a list of lists of tuples. Each list represents a week and each day is a tuple of the day of the month and the week day. I wish to make my month a list of lists of month days. I tried to do it like this:

```
for week in month:
    week = [day[0] for day in week]
```

for `[[(1, 1), (2, 2)], [(3, 3), (4, 4)]]` I expect to get `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`, but the list doesn't change. To my understanding of python my code is perfectly fine, so what am I missing? Isn't `week` a reference to each week in the month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the variable you are iterating on is never a "reference" (as in C++'s reference).

You should understand the `for` loop as

```
month_iter = iter(month)
try:
  while True:
    week = next(month_iter)
    # here begins your code
    week = [day[0] for day in week]
    # here ends your code
except StopIteration:
  pass
```

Clearly, the 2nd assignment won't affect the content of `month`.

You could just write

```
month = [[day[0] for day in week] for week in month]
```

to replace the whole `month` list, or use `enumerate` as stated in [@Ivo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590222/cannot-change-content-of-list-within-list-can-anybody-explain-why/3590234#3590234).

Answer (score 2):

By assigning something to week, you change what the variable is bound to, not what the list contains. To do what you want to do without many changes, do:

```
for week in month:
    week[:] = [day[0] for day in week]
```

It will assign the result to a specified range inside `week` - in this case, the whole range, replacing all existing elements.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment in python is merely attaching a name to an object, it's not an operation on the object itself (but do not confuse this with getting/setting attributes on an object)

if you have

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x[1]
```

Then y will simply be 2 and lose all reference to the list it came from. Changing y will not change x. To do so, index x properly.

In your case, you want to iterate over the indexes of month and assign to the appropriate entry

```
for index, week in enumerate(month):
    month[index] = [day[0] for day in week]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
>>> foo = []
>>> for week in month:
...     foo.append([day[0] for day in week])
... 
>>> foo
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Simple to read, simple to understand, ...

Comment: I know I can work around my problem, I just wanted to know why the way I did it didn't work and what is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Ok.
But why would you want to do it like you did.
IMHO it's not "pythonic" (Zen of Python: Simple is better than complex.)
;)